# Spark/Scala 1.6 how to use dataframe groupby agg to implement following logical?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to use dataframe  groupby agg to implement following logical?

```
ID    ID2   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6 .....C33
CM1    a    1    1    1    0    0    0
CM2    a    1    1    0    1    0    0
CM3    a    1    0    1    1    1    0
CM4    a    1    1    1    1    1    0
CM5    a    1    1    1    1    1    0
1k2    b    0    0    1    1    1    0
1K3    b    1    1    1    1    1    0
1K1    b    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

I would like my output df to look like this

```
ID    ID2   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6 .....C33
CM1    a    1    1    1    0    0    0
CM2    a    0    0    0    1    0    0
CM3    a    0    0    0    0    1    0
CM4    a    0    0    0    0    0    0
CM5    a    0    0    0    0    0    0
1K1    b    0    0    0    0    1    0
1k2    b    0    0    1    1    0    0
1K3    b    1    1    0    0    0    0
```

The logic is based on ID2 do group by , and then find the minimum ID when Cn is 1 then set to 1, the others are set to 0.

And Cn up to C33.

If use case class will exceed the limit.

I have tried use mapPartitions

But the result was wrong...

Use Spark 1.6.0

---

add the code I have tried

```
case class testGoods(ID: String, ID2: String, C1 : String, C2 : String)

val cartMap = new HashMap[String, Set[(String,String,String)]] with MultiMap[String,(String,String,String)]

val baseDF=hiveContext.sql(newSql)

val testRDD=baseDF.mapPartitions( partition => {
  while (partition.hasNext) {
    val record = partition.next()
    val ID = record.getString(0)
    if (ID != null && ID != "null") {
      val ID2=record.getString(1)
      val C1=record.getString(2)
      val C2=record.getString(3)
      cartMap.addBinding(ID2, (ID,C1,C2))
    }
  }
  cartMap.iterator
})

val recordList = new mutable.ListBuffer[testGoods]()
val testRDD1=testRDD.mapPartitions( partition => {
  while (partition.hasNext) {
    val record = partition.next()
    val ID2=record._1
    val recordRow= record._2
    val sortedRecordRow = TreeSet[(String,String,String)]() ++ recordRow
    val dic=new mutable.HashMap[String,String]


    for(v<-sortedRecordRow) {
      val ID = v._1
      val C1 = v._2
      val C2 = v._3

      if (dic.contains(ID2)){
        val goodsValue=dic.get(ID2)
        if("1".equals(goodsValue)){
          recordList.append(new testGoods(ID, ID2, "0", C2))
        }else{
          dic.put(ID2,C1)
          recordList.append(new testGoods(ID, ID2, C1,C2))
        }
      }else{
        dic.put(ID2,C1)
        recordList.append(new testGoods(ID, ID2, C1, C2))
      }
    }
  }
  recordList.iterator
})
```

---

edited again

The original dataset has millions of  ID, and after group by ID, each ID2 may have  2~300 data.

Comment: can you add some code you tried?

Comment: Sure, I added some code and edited the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if your subtables are small (as you mentioned in the comment 2~300 data points), all you need is something like this:

```
val columnIds = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)// (preColumns to preColumns + numColumns).toList
val columnNames = List("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6") //just for representability

val withKey = df.rdd.map(c => c.getString(1) -> c).groupByKey

val res = withKey.flatMap{ 
  case (id, local) =>
    case class Accumulator(found: Set[Int] = Set.empty, result: List[Row] = List.empty)    
    local.foldLeft(Accumulator()){
      case (acc, row) => 
        val found = columnIds.filter(id => row.getInt(id) != 0) //columns with `1`
        val pre = Seq(row(0), row(1))
        val res = pre ++ columnIds.map{ cid => 
          if (acc.found.contains(cid)) 0 else row.get(cid)
        }
        Accumulator(acc.found ++ found, Row.fromSeq(res) :: acc.result)
    }.result.reverse
}
```

- You can get rid of `reverse` by using more appropriate collection than `List` for accumulator (like [`Queue`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html))
- `Accumulator` here is introduced in order to avoid mutable variables when representing columns for which we already found "1". However, you can use `var`'s inside lambda (but not outside!) in Spark - it will also work.
- `Accumulator` saves processed columns in `found` and the result itself in `result`.
- `groupByKey` was used because you can't access rdd inside rdd in Spark, you can do it only inside streams. It's also a "smarter" replacement for `mapPartitions` in your code - it can understand "grouping by keys" instead of partitions.
- `local` is local subset of your dataframe, you basically can operate it as a regular `Scala`-collection.

To convert `RDD` back to a `DataFrame`:

```
val newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(res, df.schema)
```

Experiment:

```
data.csv:
ID,ID2,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6
CM1,a,1,1,1,0,0,0
CM2,a,1,1,0,1,0,0
CM3,a,1,0,1,1,1,0
1k2,b,0,0,1,1,1,0
1K3,b,1,1,1,1,1,0
1K1,b,0,0,0,0,1,0

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data.csv")
...
res.collect()

res77_4: Array[Row] = Array(
[CM1,a,1,1,1,0,0,0],
  [CM2,a,0,0,0,1,0,0],
  [CM3,a,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [1k2,b,0,0,1,1,1,0],
  [1K3,b,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [1K1,b,0,0,0,0,0,0]
)
```

---

For other cases dealing with sparse data (with a lot of zeros) - consider using Mllib's matrices: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-data-types.html#distributed-matrix. They can save and process sparse structures more efficiently.

I'd also recommend represinting `Row` with a case-class to avoid using column indices.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Another question, if my subtables are large, how would I change the code? I found out one of my subtables has 30000 data points and might throw an error: Listener SQLListener threw an exception:java.lang.NullPointerException, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Original dataset is about 20G and has 250 columns.So I changed some code.
val columnIds =(213 to 245).toList
 val withKey = baseDF.rdd.map(c => c.getString(129) -> c).groupByKey 
 val pre = (0 to 212).map(i=>row(i))

Comment: @user3127157 30000 isn't too much, IMO. Anyway,if you actually face scalability issue  there are  several options, but as long as your dataset is sorted by id2, you can introduce some subkey and store accumulator's flags ("found") per subkey (or even per record in sub-key) and merge subkeys at second stage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's algorithm how I've solved this issue. Definitely there is plenty room for improve.
Basically I propose to resolve it 2 phases.

1. Build a map of Ids for each first `1` in a dataset.
2. Map full data frame based on this map - replacing all non satisfying records with `0`

`val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data.csv")`

```
val Limit = 5 // or 33

val re = (1 to Limit).map { i =>
    val col = "C" + i
    val first = df.filter(df(col) > 0).head
    val id  = first(0) // id column name
    i -> id
}.toMap
// result of this stage is smth like:Map(5 -> CM3, 1 -> CM1, 2 -> CM1, 3 -> CM1, 4 -> CM2)    

df.map(columns => 
     Seq(columns(0), columns(1)) ++ 
        (1 to Limit).map { x => 
             if (columns(0) == re(x)) 1 else 0 
      }).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I edited the example for 0 situations, it's caused java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator

Comment: It seems you ignored `ID2`-grouping. As I understand the goal is to apply this logic `ID2`-wise

Comment: @dk14 there was nothing about id2 grouping in original enquiry. But if user understood concept it's easy to apply another grouping layer.

Comment: @user3127157 - most likely it's because you have column with zeros without any 1s. Try to debug proposed solution. Check what is output of `re`

Comment: it's not easy to apply a grouping layer in spark-sql (or even rdd) without giving up scalability. So the question to @user3127157 is how many "a"s are actually in the table

Comment: Agree.. I was thinking about smth like `for_each_unique_id2` repeat code from my answer.

Comment: @Rumoku Sorry about that. The original dataset has millions of  ID, and after group by ID, each ID2 may have  2~300 data.